# Detect if a form has unsaved changes before letting user focus to a different form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to detect if user has changed from the content of one section to another in the same page?

I have a page with multiple buttons (1 form/section is opened once you click on each button), when they all are closed i can detect user is changing to another form using a click event on the button element.

**My sections in this case are forms loaded when you click on every button in the page. pure jquery to load the content via ajax inside them.**

The problem is when all sections are open. I need to detect when user has changed between the content of one section to another.

I have to warn the user about saving your changes in a previous form because system has a timeout for inactivity, if user didnt save his data, it is lost once user gets logout from application.

*the event prompt the user to save the data of the previous form.*

The only way I can think of doing this is using a mouse event, but this can sometimes be a frustrating experience.

***Solved***

Thanks DelightedD0D, I ended up doing this

This var saves the previous form number

```
var pendingForm = [];
```

Events which fire a possible warning

```
//Pressing tab is reviewed if there are unsaved changes in the previous section.
$(document).keyup(function(eventTab) {
    var code = eventTab.keyCode || eventTab.which;
    if (code === 9) {
        checkPrevious(eventTab);
    }
});
//Clicking is reviewed if there are unsaved changes in the previous section
$(document).mouseup(function(eventMouse) {
    checkPrevious(eventMouse);
});
```

Here we establish when a form is pending or has changed

```
$('.formSection').on('keyup change', 'input, select, textarea', function() {
  $(this).closest('.formSection').addClass('pending');
  //We get the number of the form by the id
  var numForm = $(this).closest('.formSection').attr('id').substr(11, 2);
  if ( $.inArray(numForm , pendingForm) == -1 ) {
    pendingForm.push(numForm);
  }
});

//I have my own functions to save and cancel, but the idea is Save the data
//then find the formSection from previous form, remove pending class and
//remove number form from array of pending sections
$('.save').click(function() {
  //save data...
  var numForm = pendingForm.pop();
  $('#formSection'+numForm).removeClass('pending');
});
```

And this function checks when user move to another form

```
function checkPrevious(e) {
    var $target = $(e.target);
    //If it is clicked somewhere within a form or a button that opens a section
    if ($target.closest('.formSection').length || $target.hasClass('btnSection')) {
        var isDisabled = false;
        if (pendingForm.length > 0) {
            prevForm = pendingForm.slice(-1).pop();
            //Every submit form button has an id with a consecutive number in my case
            //If disabled, that means it has errors in validation (Bootstrap)
            //**I have to improve this verification yet**
            isDisabled = $('#submitForm' + prevForm).is(':disabled');
        }

        // get any forms with changes that are not the current form or do not contain the clicked element
        var $otherFormsWithChanges = $('.pending').filter(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            return $this.hasClass('pending') && (!$this.is($target) || $this.has($target).length != 0);
        });
        // if another form has a change, thow up a message
        // allow the user to go back to the form or ignore the changes
        if ($otherFormsWithChanges.length > 0 && $otherFormsWithChanges.has($target).length === 0 ) {
            var modalPrev = $('#modalPrev');
            if ( isDisabled == false ) {
                //If everything is ok, we can save
                modalPrev.find('.modal-content .modal-body').html("<p>You have unsaved changes. Do you want to save previous form?</p>");
                modalPrev.find(".btnSave").removeClass('hide');
            } else {
                modalPrev.find('.modal-content .modal-body').html("<p>You have some errors in your previous form.</p>");
                modalPrev.find(".btnSave").addClass('hide');
            }
            $('#modalPrev').modal('show');
        }
    }
}
```

I show a modal instead of an alert with two buttons [Save] and [Cancel], every one has a function which do a save or close but both remove the previous section from the array to not be considered anymore.

Comment: What do you mean by "This can sometimes be a frustrating experience"?

Comment: I mean, you can move the mouse out of the form by accident and launch the event every time. happens to me a lot.

Comment: Would it work to put the warning in a timer that ran if they left a form for longer than a couple seconds? (I ask this because I can't really tell from your post exactly *why* the need an alert. Depending on what you were doing, I'd potentially suggest something else.)

Comment: I think it could reduce the number of events released. but there is no other way to achieve this?. Im trying to warn the user about saving his changes in a previous form, each tab has a form, but sometimes user forget to click on Save button and the session component when time has finished just logout him.

Comment: So you have a list of forms and they each need filled out 1 by 1? After a user has left one form and went to the next one after it, you want to make sure he saved his information? Am I correct so far? (Another thing, what do you mean by 'the session component'? Is this a javascript thing, or not?)

Comment: Can you please be more specific with the definition of "tab"? Are you using some framework? If you can - provide a working example, it will help with a solution to your problem.

Comment: ok, added clarification, no more tabs, are sections loaded by buttons. No special framework used for this. just a bunch of buttons which load a form that can be modified. If user decides to fill another section/form without save first previous i need to warn him. I just want to know a way to detect when user does the change between sections.

Comment: Could you use something like this: `when user leave form {set lastForm = formLeft}; on user enter form {if lastForm != null and lastFormNotSaved, print warning}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by setting a class on the form when input values change then listening for clicks on the document and checking if a form other than the one being interacted with has changes. If one does, present a message to the user.

This should work:

**Note** that you dont *have to use forms*, just add the `track-changes` class to some parent of the inputs you have grouped together

#### [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/yjj9boou/10/)

```js
$(document).mouseup(function(e) { 
  var $target = $(e.target);   
  // get any forms with changes that are not the current form or do not contain the clicked element
  var $otherFormsWithChanges = $('.pending').filter(function() {
    var $this=$(this); 
    return $this.hasClass('pending') && (!$this.is($target) || $this.has($target).length !=0);
  }); 
  // if another form has a change, thow up a message
  // allow the user to go back to the form or ignore the changes
  if ($otherFormsWithChanges.length > 0 && $otherFormsWithChanges.has($target).length===0 ) { 
    var c = confirm("You have unsaved changes.\n\n Click cancel to go back to the unsaved form or OK to ignore");
    c ? $otherFormsWithChanges.removeClass('pending') : $otherFormsWithChanges.find('input, select, textarea').focus();  
  }
});

$('.track-changes').on('keyup change', 'input, select, textarea', function() {
  $(this).closest('.track-changes').addClass('pending'); 
});

$('.save').click(function() {
  // save data...
  $(this).closest('.track-changes').removeClass('pending'); 
});
```

```css
form{
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>form 1</h4>
<form class="track-changes" has-changes="false" action="">
  <input type="text">
  some text
  <br>
  <button type="button" class="save">Save</button>
</form>

<h4>form 2</h4>
<form class="track-changes" has-changes="false" action="">
  <input type="text">
  some text
  <br>
  <button type="button" class="save">Save</button>
</form>

<h4>form 3</h4>
<form class="track-changes" has-changes="false" action="">
  <input type="text">
  some text
  <br>
  <button type="button" class="save">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for this great explanation, you understand me perfectly, this do the trick indeed =). I wish I could find a way to do without using mouse event, but it seems that is the only way, but seeing it in this way sounds more logical now.